# Less noisy graph and extra humps in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, noise

Here is the data file:

https://jsfiddle.net/83ygso6u/

Sorry for posting it in jsfiddle... didn't know where else to host it.

Anyway the second column should be ignored.

Here is the code and graph:

```
import pylab as plb
import math
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = plb.loadtxt('title_of_datafile.txt')  
x = data[:,0]*1000
y= data[:,2]

plt.figure()

plt.title('Some_Title',fontsize=35, y=1.05)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)',fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('dBu',fontsize=30)

plt.plot(x,y,'k-', label='Data')

plt.xticks(fontsize = 25, y=-0.008)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25, x=-0.008)
plt.show()
```

[image]

So you can see this signal is quite noisy, but it does have two distinct peaks at around 4500 Hz and 5500 Hz.

I have been searching around the net and havn't really come across anything that will help me.

How can I extract these peaks and/or clean up the signal in python?

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to find a solution. Here is the script with the resulting plot.

Script:

```
import pylab as plb
import math
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import peakutils
from peakutils.plot import plot as pplot

data = plb.loadtxt('data_file_name')  
x = data[:,0]*1000
y= data[:,2]

y1 = sp.signal.medfilt(y,431) # remove noise to the signal

indexes = peakutils.indexes(y1, thres=0.00005, min_dist=1400) #determine peaks
x_new = x[indexes]

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)

plt.title('some_title_1',fontsize=35, y=1.05)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)',fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Signal (dBu)',fontsize=30)
plt.plot(x,y,'r-', label='Raw Data')
plt.plot(x,y1,'b-', label='Cleaned up Signal')
plt.plot(x_new[3:6],y1[indexes][3:6],'k^',markersize=10, label='Peaks')
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25, y=-0.008)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25, x=-0.008)
plt.legend(loc=1,prop={'size':30})

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
for i,j in zip(x_new[3:6], y1[indexes][3:6]):
    plt.annotate(str(i)+ " Hz",xy=(i,j+0.5),fontsize=15)
plt.title('some_title_2',fontsize=35, y=1.05)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)',fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Signal (dBu)',fontsize=30)
plt.plot(x,y,'r-', label='Data')
plt.plot(x,y1,'b-')
plt.plot(x_new[3:6],y1[indexes][3:6],'k^',markersize=10)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25, y=-0.008)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25, x=-0.008)
plt.xlim([3000, 6000])
plt.ylim([-90, -75])
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]